# How to find out who manages funds?

Tags: mutual-funds, etf, risk

So I am interested in a fund.  I want to know if I can trust the people running it.  I don't know however, how to find out who they are.  I have thee name of the company offering the firm but no individuals.

How can I evaluate my trust for this fund/organization?

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the US, your local library probably has access to Morning Star, which has details about funds, performance and the team managing them.

Comment: This is the beginning of a summary statement This investment seeks to provide investment results that correspond generally to the price and yield performance, before fees and expenses, of the INDXX ... Thematic Index.  Does this imply that there is a manager or does the management come form the index it is based on?

Answer (score 2):

All legitimate mutual funds are required to provide a financial fact sheet going over a lot of relevant information including the fund manager, past performance, fees charged etc. Search for the fact sheet of the fund that you want to invest in and you should find what you are looking for.